# Wildfly9 external logging.properties

Tags: logging, properties, wildfly, external

I have some webapp with restservices on wildfly 9.
Each war contains a logging.properties with some configuration and the log file path (configured for the test, stage and production environment).

I know wildfly automatically read and load this file if it exists but is there a way to externalize this properties file such as for all other properties file in spring?

In this way I can configure the log file path differently for each environment.

Comment: Is this a Spring specific `logging.properties` or one readable via the jboss-logmanager?

Comment: It's a automatically read by jboss (logmanager), no spring file.
I found a property ${jboss.server.log.dir} used by jboss that point to the log dir but I don't know how to define a new property or override this one.

Comment: So the question is how to define a new "relative-to" path?

Comment: This could be a good question.. Another question is "How to define a logging.properties for each war on wildfly server"

Comment: You can just include a `logging.properties` in each deployment or you could use [logging-profiles](http://docs.wildfly.org/12/Admin_Guide.html#logging-profiles) which would give you the ability to make changes at runtime.

Comment: Yes I just use a logging.properties into my wars, but if I want to change the level I need to redeploy the app. I'm going to know something more about logging-profiles. Thanks ;)

Comment: A logging profile would be the way to do that. You can't make runtime changes with a `logging.properties` file as it's only read once.